# eccentric anomaly expansion equation

Tags: simplifying-expressions, series-expansion

I try to use this simple algorithm ([paper](http://www.professores.uff.br/diomar_cesar_lobao/material/Astro-Dio/SAB97-CERCA.pdf)) to calculate the Eccentric Anomaly expansion:

```
a[0]=0;
Do [
t1 = 1-a[k-1]^2/2+a[k-1]^4/24;
t2 = a[k-1]-a[k-1]^3/6;
a[k]=Expand[e*Sin[u]*t1+e*Cos[u]*t2,Trig->True];
Simplify[a[k]];
TeXForm[a[k]] >>"tex.01";
Print [a[k],k], {k,2}]
```

The result should be this one [image: from Paper]

but maybe because the algorithm is write with an old version of Mathematica I have as an output this different (in terms of trigonometric function)
[image: result]

How can I re-arrange it to have the one in the paper? And when I have the result of the paper is it possible, then, to regroup the equation in terms of power series of sin(u), something like that:

[image: equation]

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear[a]

a[0] = 0;
a[k_] := a[k] =
  e*Sin[u]*(1 - a[k - 1]^2/2 + a[k - 1]^4/24) +
     e*Cos[u]*(a[k - 1] - a[k - 1]^3/6) // 
 TrigReduce // Expand; 

TraditionalForm /@ a[2]
```

[image]

```
TraditionalForm /@ (a[2] // Collect[#, Table[Sin[n*u], {n, 5}]] &)
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I'am looking for! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be several issues here.

1. The *Mathematica* code seems strange, arguably miswritten, though it appears you transcribed it correctly.

   - `Simplify[a[k]];` doesn't appear to do anything; it's output is never assigned
   - Placing `TeXForm[a[k]] >>"tex.01";` within the loop writes that file, then overwrites it in the next iteration.  Perhaps `>>>` ([`PutAppend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PutAppend.html)) was intended?
2. `TeXForm` reorders terms as a result of using [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TraditionalForm.html), and it seems you do not want that reordering
3. Even when [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Simplify.html) is actually applied the results (using v10) differ from what you show.  [`Expand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Expand.html) seems to help.

Perhaps this gets you close enough:

```
a[0] = 0;

Do[t1 = 1 - a[k - 1]^2/2 + a[k - 1]^4/24;
 t2 = a[k - 1] - a[k - 1]^3/6;
 a[k] = Expand[e*Sin[u]*t1 + e*Cos[u]*t2, Trig -> True];
 a[k] = Simplify @ a[k],
 {k, 2}
]

TeXForm[HoldForm @@ {Expand @ a[2]}]
```

> $e \sin (u)-\frac{1}{4} e^3 \sin (u)+\frac{1}{64} e^5 \sin (u)+e^2 \cos (u) \sin
>    (u)-\frac{1}{24} e^4 \cos (u) \sin (u)+\frac{1}{4} e^3 \cos (2 u) \sin
>    (u)-\frac{1}{48} e^5 \cos (2 u) \sin (u)+\frac{1}{24} e^4 \cos (3 u) \sin
>    (u)+\frac{1}{192} e^5 \cos (4 u) \sin (u)$